# application manifest cannot be reached

Tags: c#, clickonce

I have published an application on dropbox, which runs fine if ran locally, or if installed offline. While trying to install it from [this link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ytl78uqgz97fjp9/%CE%94%CE%91%CE%9D%CE%95%CE%99%CE%9A%CE%91%20%CE%97%CE%9C%CE%95%CE%A1%CE%91%CE%A3.application?dl=0)

Specifically the error is: The Deployment Provider specified in the manifest cannot be reached. Maybe due to network error and/or the deployment provider is not responding correctly.

I have tried setting the manifest in Project>Properties>Application to "Create application without a manifest", but the manifest file exists still, and the problem persists.